# TFS automatically checks out a project when loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control-explorer

This is very weird behavior of Visual studio and TFS. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012. We have a large number of projects and solutions in the source control.

Lets assume I have no pending changes.

Whenever I open solutions which are present on source control all projects are loaded. And not a single project is checked-out for edit. I can see lock icon with the projects in the solution explorer.

Now I create a new solution and add projects from the source control to this solution, I face weird behavior. Some of the projects are automatically checked out and I haven't did any change to it. And this happens to only few projects instead of all projects. If I call undo all pending changes TFS perform a undo but then calls checkout for the project.

What is the proper solution to it. And it happens only in custom solution (sln) which is not present in the source control.

Comment: You say that the projects are checked out - exactly which files are checked out? Are there new pending changes?

Comment: Only csproj files are checked out, all cs files are locked. In pending changes I see csproj file checked out.

Comment: Have you done a compare to see if anything changed in the csproj?

Comment: Compare says files are same,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez : Have you gotten your answer? I have the same problem